# C#/Xamarin - Java Lib integration. How to get the correct method?

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
IntPtr Map_defCtor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(Map_Class, "<init>", "(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)V");
```

This causes the error

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/myPackage/MyObject;.(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)V"

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you being cute? Those are the inputs for the Constructor. Are they passed in correctly, is my question. Example, Ljava, or does it need slash, or whatever is specific to C# that I am missing out.

Comment: With or without the "V" will cause the error.